# Pandas stacked multilevel index plot

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, pandas, rpy2

I would like to make a stacked bar plot for one index level, while the other remains unstacked. The code below create tuples for each index row:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, MultiIndex
from numpy import repeat
from numpy.random import randn
arrays = [repeat('a b'.split(),2),[True,False,True,False]]
midx = MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(*arrays), names=['letters','bool'])
df = DataFrame(randn(4,2)**2+5, index=midx)
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.legend(loc="center right", bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, 0.5), ncol=2)
```

[image]
[image]

But I would rather want to see (0,1) grouped side by side, as when using this R code (in IPython):

```
%load_ext rmagic
dr = df.stack().reset_index()
```

and then

```
%%R -i dr

library(ggplot2)
names(dr) <- c('letters','bool','n','value')

    x <- ggplot() +
      geom_bar(data=dr, aes(y = value, x = letters, fill = bool), 
               stat="identity", position='stack') +
      theme_bw() + 
      facet_grid( ~ n)

print(x)
```

[image]

Now: Is there a way of doing this within **pandas**, should I torture **matplotlib** instead, should I install [**ggplot for python**](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/ggplot-for-python.html) or should I just run **ggplot2** in IPython using the Rmagic (as I just did)? I could not get **rpy2**'s ggplot class

```
from rpy2.robjects.lib import ggplot2
```

to work with my layout (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the R code, porting to rpy2 can be taken progressively

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

ro.globalenv['dr'] = dr

ro.r("""
library(ggplot2)
names(dr) <- c('letters','bool','n','value')

x <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=dr, aes(y = value, x = letters, fill = bool), 
           stat="identity", position='stack') +
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_grid( ~ n)

print(x)
""")
```

The drawback with this is that R's GlobalEnv is used. A function can be more elegant.

```
make_plot = ro.r("""
function(dr) {
  names(dr) <- c('letters','bool','n','value')

  x <- ggplot() +
    geom_bar(data=dr, aes(y = value, x = letters, fill = bool), 
             stat="identity", position='stack') +
    theme_bw() + 
    facet_grid( ~ n)

  print(x)
}""")

make_plot(dr)
```

An alternative is to use the ggplot2 mapping in rpy2, and write this without writting
R code:

```
from rpy2.robjects import Formula
from rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 import ggplot, geom_bar, aes_string, theme_bw, facet_grid

## oddity with names in the examples, that can either be corrected in the Python-pandas
## structure or with an explicit conversion into an R object and renaming there
drr = rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri.pandas2ri(dr)
drr.names[2] = 'n'
drr.names[3] = 'value'

p = ggplot(drr) + \
    geom_bar(aes_string(x="letters", y="value", fill="bool"),
             stat="identity", position="stack") + \
    theme_bw() + \
    facet_grid(Formula('~ n'))

p.plot()
```

Comment: Did you run #3? I'm getting `RRuntimeError: Error in layout_base(data, cols, drop = drop) : At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting`

Comment: @dmvianna : I did not - the presence of a `form ... import ...` rather than `from ... import ...` in the code (now corrected) was there as a confirmation. Otherwise it was only a matter of a misplaced parenthesis (`stat` and `position` are parameters for `geom_bar()`, not `aes_string` - the error message from R/ggplot2 was not very informative, but it would have been the same when in R).

Comment: OK, now it is failing silently. I'm on IPython 1.1.0, pandas 0.12.0, rpy2 2.3.8

Comment: The "failing silently" bit suggests that the plot might be showing up where you do not expect it (e.g., window in the background, or file if R is in in non-interactive mode, running on a server without X, or if a file-based graphical device is open). I tried this with Python 3.3.2, pandas 0.12.0, rpy2-2.4.0-dev.

Comment: I'm running IPython notebook on a remote server. I would really like to see the result in IPython, but a fallback option would be to print it to a file (which I will also need eventually). The server can run X, but I never do. Running ggplot through the rmagic gives me no issues.

Comment: `rmagic` is built on the top of `rpy2`, but is naturally also adding a layer specific to ipython. If wanting to have ggplot2 figures in ipython without writing R, take a look at this example: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5180089 .

Comment: Phew! Got it. It is very confusing that there is a rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2.ggplot method (which is silent in IPython) and a separate rpy2.interactive.ipython.ggplot method that works as expected. Is this documented yet? Thanks for all your help and for Rpy2!

Comment: With `rmagic` moving to rpy2 (branch `version_2.4.x`), the integration with ipython should be smoother and better documented. Feedback is welcome (visit the bitbucket page for rpy2).